# Media queries not working on resize

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I was looking for some help in regards to media queries. This is the first time I am using this on a site, but it doesn't seem to work. This is also the first time I am changing my html4 code to html5, not sure if that's where the problem lies.

My HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html> <!-- html5 doctype -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- line added to for responsive layout -->
<title>Dummy Site</title>
<link href="style5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header></header>
        <div id="spacer1"></div>
        <div id="banner"></div>
        <div id="range"></div>
        <div id="spacer2"></div>
        <div id="cols"></div>
        <div id="spacer3"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#f5f3ef; 
}

a {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #66308f;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  }

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1264px;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1264px;
    width: 893px;
    background-color:#0CF;
}

header {
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 171px;
    width: 883px;
}

#spacer1 {
    height:59px;
}

#banner {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 883px;
    height: 439px;  
    background:url(z_imgs/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#range {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 246px;
    width: 883px;
}

#spacer2 {
    height:24px;
}

#cols {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:188px;
    width:883px;
}

#spacer3 {
    height:39px;
}

footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:98px;
    width:883px;
}

<!-- MEDIA QUERIES -->
@media (max-width: 850px) {
    #wrapper {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

When I resize the browser to below 850px the color still stays the same and doesn't change to red.

Comment: Hi Michael. Would you consider accepting the below answer? To do so, click on the tick mark to the left of the answer, so the question is marked as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work since you are using **HTML comments** inside **CSS code** which leads to syntax error and browser not recognizing the code. Remove the comment or modify it from `<!-- -->` to `/* */` and it works.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f5f3ef;
}
a {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #66308f;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1264px;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1264px;
  width: 893px;
  background-color: #0CF;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 171px;
  width: 883px;
}
#spacer1 {
  height: 59px;
}
#banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 883px;
  height: 439px;
  background: url(z_imgs/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#range {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 246px;
  width: 883px;
}
#spacer2 {
  height: 24px;
}
#cols {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 188px;
  width: 883px;
}
#spacer3 {
  height: 39px;
}
footer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 98px;
  width: 883px;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  #wrapper {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- html5 doctype -->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- line added to for responsive layout -->
  <title>Dummy Site</title>
  <link href="style5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header></header>
      <div id="spacer1"></div>
      <div id="banner"></div>
      <div id="range"></div>
      <div id="spacer2"></div>
      <div id="cols"></div>
      <div id="spacer3"></div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No worries. It happens ;)